# Some Literate tool to create fast Mind maps in RSweaveLatex?

Tags: sweave, r, mindmaps

I am looking for literate tools for mind-map-generation that would work nicely with RSweaveLatex. It is possible that there is no need for tools such as Labyrithm (which is apparently broken, at least in Ubuntu) or Dia (stopped to use it a long time ago) but I could reuse the existing software packages.

I was unable to find any such pkg [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_date.html) or I am using wrong words. Anyway I am looking for some literate mind-map-tool which I could use as spontaneously as RSweaveLatex, otherwise I will use just pen-and-paper!

*Perhaps, some label such as `creativity` or something like that would describe this kind of innovative questions that do not necessarily have solution -- but trying to find a certain type of solution, perhaps not existing yet.*

Comment: There's a mindmap library as part of the LaTeX package `tikz`. Whether or not this could be generated via R, I don't know/.

Comment: @AlanMunn: yes and there is quite young project for this [here](https://github.com/Sharpie/RTikZDevice), interesting...have to try whether it fits my needs.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not what you mean but you may want to check it out anyway: [Semantik](http://www.freehackers.org/~tnagy/kdissert.html) and [vym](http://www.insilmaril.de/vym/) can both export to LaTeX. They give you a .tex file, structured along the lines of the mindmap you have created with them. Some rough edges, but I have used both of them and found them helpful.